# New / Old Instagram API - using old functionality with already registered client

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Since Instagram released their new API, on their DEV-page they say:

> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 2016.

I wonder if thats means that the app just needs to be registered before that date in order to be able to use all the functions of the old API, even if they are not implemented yet. Or is there something else to take into consideration?

I registered an application before that date and wanted to make use of the Realtime functions. Those are not implemented in my application yet. Can I go on implementing as long as I don't want to use the application longer than until June 2016?

Thanks in advance if anyone has more information on this issue!

Answer (score 0):

As reported into [Instagram ChangeLog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/) :
**Apps created before Nov 17, 2015
are Unaffected by new API behavior**

So I am pretty sure that you are right saying this:
*"that the app just needs to be registered before that date in order to be able to use all the functions of the old API, even if they are not implemented yet"*

Hope it helps!